# How to trigger certain functionality on successful room migration?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I am migrating my code to Room and I facing specific issue where I have to trigger service with specific intent on successful migration. I could not find way to execute code on successful migration.

```
Room.databaseBuilder(
            context,
            AppDatabase::class.java, "mydb"
        ).addMigrations(migration67)
```